# Amazon S3 403 Forbidden Error for KML files but not JPG files

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I am able to successfully upload (put object) jpg files to S3 with a particular code path, but receive a 403 forbidden error when using the same code path to upload a KML file. I am not restricting file types explicitly with "bucket policy," but feel that this must somehow be tied to bucket policy or CORS configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using code based off the Heroku tutorial for uploading images to Amazon S3. The issue ended up being that the '+' symbol in the appropriate mime type is "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" and the + symbol was being replaced with a space when fetching the file-type query parameter for our own S3 endpoint to generate signed requests. We were able to quickly fix this by just forcing the ContentType to be "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" for all kml files going to our endpoint for generating signed S3 requests.